# Execution flow of a storm program

Tags: apache-storm

I am new in storm and trying to understand the flow of execution of different methods from `spout` to `bolt` . 
Like spout has different methods like

> nextTuple()
>
> open()
>
> declareOutputFields()
>
> activate()
>
> deactivate()

and bolt has methods like

> prepare()
>
> execute()
>
> cleanup()
>
> declareOutputFields()

so can anyone tell me the sequence of execution of these methods ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, when your **topology** is started...

1. Create Spouts and Bolts
2. `declareOutputFields`
3. Spouts/Bolts serialized and assigned to workers

Second, in each worker somewhere on the cluster...

1. Spouts `open` and Bolts `prepare` (happens once)
2. In a loop...

   - Spouts call `ack`, `fail`, and `nextTuple`
   - Bolts call `execute`

---

If your topology is deactivated...

- Your spouts `deactivate` method will be called. When you activate the topology again then `activate` will be called.

If your topology is killed...

- Spouts **might** have `close` called
- Bolts **might** have `cleanup` called

Note:

> There is no guarentee that close will be called, because the
>   supervisor kill -9's worker processes on the cluster. [source](http://storm.apache.org/apidocs/backtype/storm/spout/ISpout.html)

Comment: Thanks of the answer.
I have one more question if you can help -when i kill the topology the cleanup method do not get called since i am running in cluster mode so if i want to execute a code after the topology being killed where can i write that code ?

Comment: So far I haven't found a good way to execute code when the topology is being killed. I've thought about trying to add a "graceful shutdown" mechanism using zookeeper but so far haven't had time to work on it. If you get something working I'd be interested!