# Creating multiple sessions of Topic tibco ems when connecting to storm bolts through apache-camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, apache-storm, tibco-ems

I am working on apache storm and I plan to connect the end bolts to pass messages to a topic of tibco-ems using Apache-camel through a single tibco-ems connection, but each instance of the bolt should have a separate session with the topic to avoid overloading as the amount of messages to be transferred is huge. How do I create separate sessions ? I have instantiated the camel-context in the prepare method of the bolt class and the routes and tibco ems connection is being instantiated in the config file.

camel-context is instantiated according to the solution in the below link:
[Using Apache Camel ProducerTemplate in Apache Storm bolt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29913304/using-apache-camel-producertemplate-in-apache-storm-bolt)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused when you say "tibco ems connection is being instantiated in the config file".

Remember `prepare` is going to execute once for **each instance of your bolt**, so this is where you would initialize your connection to tibco ems. Just like `ProducerTemplate` you could make your connection `transient` since you'll re-use over and over again in `execute`.

Take a look at my other answer here: [Execution flow of a storm program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28981197/execution-flow-of-a-storm-program/29015063#29015063)

Lastly, you control how many instances of your bolt you want when you setup the topology.

Comment: Hi  Kit, this is the main issue. I want multiple instances of bolt to use a single tibco connection. Basically, create multiple sessions for a single connection such that each bolt instance is connected to a session. I am using apache camel for my connection.